# Java: Image appearing very small in JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jpanel

So I have an image being drawn inside a JPanel which itself is added to a JFrame. However when the Image is first drawn it appears to be very small. I'm not sure if this is a problem with the panel or a problem with the image. It is illustrated below:
![enter image description here][1]

I have drawn a rectangle around the image.

Now the JPanel is supposed to be contained within the JFrame. The JFrame is not supposed to be coloured in as is seen above. The JPanel is meant to be about a quarter of the size of the JFrame and the image is supposed to take up almost all of the JPanel.

Could you please tell me if it's the image which is the problem or the Panel. Sorry if it seems obvious.

Awaiting SSCCE

Answer (score 5):

I have no idea what you are doing based on the few random lines of code you posted. Nowhere in the code do you actually create/read an image.

As far as I know a Mandelbrot Set is actually done by painting code. If so the problem is probably that you did not override the `getPreferredSize()` (don't use the setSize() method) of you painting panel to return the size of the image you are painting. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Paining](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information.

Or if you are actually using an existing image then read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for working examples of using images.

Also, components should be added to the frame BEFORE you make the frame visible.

If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Sorry if it was vague, I've now included the code which draws the image.

Comment: @user3352349 `I've now included the code which draws the image` - doesn't help. Still doesn't help. We still have no idea how the draw() method is invoked. It looks like you are painting to a BufferedImage but we have no idea where you actually paint the BufferedImage to the panel or for that matter why you are not using a JLabel to display the BufferedImage. Did you add debug code to display the size of Dimension of your size variable? Again if you need more help poat a proper SSCCE

Answer (score 1):

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file); //Read image through BufferedReader

labelimage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(labelimage.getWidth(), labelimage.getHeight(), image.SCALE_SMOOTH))); // This line will automaticallically set Image size equal to size of Jlabel
```

Answer (score -1):

how about adding a label inside the panel, and draw the image using `setIcon(..)`

usually I use the following class to make the image fit to the label size (I make my label has static size - not resizable).. you might wanna modify it to suit your need..

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class CustomImageIcon extends ImageIcon {

    private BufferedImage dest;

    public CustomImageIcon(String filename) {
        super(filename);
    }

    public CustomImageIcon(Image image) {
        super(image);
    }

    public CustomImageIcon(URL location) {
        super(location);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {

        if(c!=null)
            dest = new BufferedImage(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        else dest = new BufferedImage(getIconWidth(), getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        ImageObserver imgObs = getImageObserver();
        if(imgObs==null) imgObs = c;

        int width;
        int height;
        if(c!=null)
        {
            width = c.getWidth();
            height = c.getHeight();
        }
        else
        {
            width = getIconWidth();
            height = getIconHeight();
        }


        g.drawImage(dest, 0, 0, c);
            g.drawImage(
                    getImage(),
                    0,
                    0,
                    width,
                    height,
                    imgObs);
    }
}
```

Comment: -1, why would you do custom painting code by extending an Icon. The point of using an Icon is to use the ImageIcon class and add the Icon to the label so you don't need to do custom painting.

Comment: as I said before, I need to make the image to automatically fit into the label regardless of the size of the image.. sometimes I have a problem with the image being not fit in the label..
sorry if this is wrong for you.. =)